# Arch: Cannot open kernel arbiter, no multicard support

Tags: arch-linux, arm, pacman

I'm currently using [Arch Linux on a Chrombook Flip C100P](https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/rockchip/asus-chromebook-flip-c100p) in conjunction with the [`xf86-video-armsoc`](https://github.com/endlessm/xf86-video-armsoc) driver.

When printing the `/dev/dri` folder on my device as `root`, it detects the following: 
`card0 controlD64 renderD120`.

However, when I last used Crouton on this device, it could detect a second card: 
`card0 card1 controlD64 renderD120`.

This was a significant difference when I used [Crouton](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-easily-install-ubuntu-chromebook-crouton) because I needed to take advantage of a [card renaming hack](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/1938) in order to launch XCFE4.

So I'm wondering, are there any possible changes I can make to my existing Arch Linux installation that would enable me to 'see' `card1`?